# How to read 'Set-Cookie' Header from 'Http-Native' plugin Ionic(3 or 4)?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I want to get or read **forbidden-header** in ionic3 or 4 , via **HTTP-Native** plugin.

**1. How to read set-cookie Header ?**

- tried several use via **GET** method [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en) or [Force-Classic-Login](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login) but , result **Set-Cookie** is **null** or **undefined**.
- provided I can see **Set-Cookie** header in Response-Header **browser** (Chrome or Firefox).